# Oracle 18 XE HS MSSQL LINUX Connecting problem

Tags: sql-server, odbc, oracle12c

I have a problem with connecting to the MSSQL database via ODBC.
The problem occurs with version 12c or 18xe, with the 11g version I connect with no problem.

my configuration:

**First server:**

- Linux Centos 7 64 bit
- Oracle 18xe unixODBC 2.3.1
- ODBC driver: MSSQL ODBC V17 (libmsodbcsql-17.2.so.0.1)

**Second server:**
Windows 2012R2
MS SQL 11.0.6020.0

**Configuration:**

/etc/odbcinst.ini:

```
[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.2.so.0.1
```

/etc/odbc.ini:

```
[MSSQL]
Driver = ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Server = 94.72.71.346
Database = DEMO
Port = 1433
Trace = yes
TraceFile /tmp/odbctrace.out
```

/opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/hs/admin/initdg4odbc.ora:

```
HS_FDS_CONNECT_INFO = MSSQL
HS_FDS_TRACE_LEVEL = DEBUG
HS_DB_NAME = DEMO
HS_AUTOREGISTER = TRUE
#HS_LANGUAGE = AL32UTF8
HS_FDS_SHAREABLE_NAME = /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.2.so.0.1
set ODBCINI=/etc/odbc.ini
```

/opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/network/admin/listener.ora:

```
DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = XE

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = vpsXXXXX.ovh.net)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )

SID_LIST_LISTENER=
    (SID_LIST=
    (SID_DESC=
      (SID_NAME=dg4odbc)
      (ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE)
      (PROGRAM=dg4odbc)
        )
    )
```

/opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/network/admin/tnsnames.ora:

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = vpsXXXXX.ovh.net)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

dg4odbc =
  (DESCRIPTION=
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost) (PORT=1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = dg4odbc))
    (HS=OK)
  )

LISTENER_XE =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = vpsXXXXX.ovh.net)(PORT = 1521))
```

/opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/network/admin/sqlnet.ora

```
# sqlnet.ora Network Configuration File: /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/network/admin/sqlnet.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

#NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)
SQLNET.INBOUND_CONNECT_TIMEOUT = 0
```

dblink:

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK "MAG"
  CONNECT TO "waproking" IDENTIFIED BY VALUES ':1'
  USING 'dg4odbc';
```

isql -v MSSQL user password works! queries also work!

Select from SQLDeveloper:

```
select * from table@mag;
```

returns the following error:

```
ORA-28511: utracono połączenie RPC z heterogenicznym odległym agentem korzystającym z SID=ORA-28511: utracono połączenie RPC z heterogenicznym odległym agentem korzystającym z SID=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=dg4odbc)))
ORA-02063: poprzedzające line z MAG
28511. 00000 -  "lost RPC connection to heterogeneous remote agent using SID=%s"
*Cause:    A fatal error occurred in one of the following places
           -- the connection between the ORACLE server and the agent
           -- the heterogeneous services remote agent itself
           -- the connection to the non-Oracle system
           This error occurred after communication had been established
           successfully.
*Action:   Check for network problems and remote host crashes. The problem is
           probably in the agent software. If so, contact a customer support
           representative of the agent vendor.
Error at Line: 1 Column: 23
```

Oracle HS log:
/opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/hs/log/dg4odbc_agt_13858.trc:

```
Oracle Corporation --- 2018-11-20 21:31:04.582408000

Heterogeneous Agent Release 
18.0.0.0.0 

Oracle Corporation --- 2018-11-20 21:31:04.582208000

    Version 18.0.0.0.0

Entered hgogprd
HOSGIP for "HS_FDS_TRACE_LEVEL" returned "DEBUG"
Entered hgosdip
 setting HS_OPEN_CURSORS to default of 50
 setting HS_NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS to default of ".,"
 HOSGIP returned value of "waproking" for HS_FDS_RECOVERY_ACCOUNT
 HOSGIP returned a value for HS_FDS_RECOVERY_PWD
 setting HS_FDS_TRANSACTION_LOG to default of HS_TRANSACTION_LOG
 setting HS_IDLE_TIMEOUT to default of 0
 setting HS_FDS_TRANSACTION_ISOLATION to default of "READ_COMMITTED"
 setting HS_NLS_NCHAR to default of "AL32UTF8"
 setting HS_FDS_TIMESTAMP_MAPPING to default of "DATE"
 setting HS_FDS_DATE_MAPPING to default of "DATE"
 setting HS_FDS_TRUNC_ANSI_DATE to default of "OFF"
 setting HS_RPC_FETCH_REBLOCKING to default of "ON"
 setting HS_FDS_FETCH_ROWS to default of "100"
 setting HS_FDS_RESULTSET_SUPPORT to default of "FALSE"
 setting HS_FDS_RSET_RETURN_ROWCOUNT to default of "FALSE"
 setting HS_FDS_PROC_IS_FUNC to default of "FALSE"
 setting HS_FDS_MAP_NCHAR to default of "TRUE"
 setting HS_NLS_DATE_FORMAT to default of "YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS"
 setting HS_FDS_REPORT_REAL_AS_DOUBLE to default of "FALSE"
 setting HS_LONG_PIECE_TRANSFER_SIZE to default of "65536"
 setting HS_SQL_HANDLE_STMT_REUSE to default of "FALSE"
 setting HS_FDS_QUERY_DRIVER to default of "TRUE"
 setting HS_FDS_SUPPORT_STATISTICS to default of "FALSE"
 setting HS_FDS_QUOTE_IDENTIFIER to default of "TRUE"
 setting HS_KEEP_REMOTE_COLUMN_SIZE to default of "OFF"
 setting HS_FDS_GRAPHIC_TO_MBCS to default of "FALSE"
 setting HS_FDS_MBCS_TO_GRAPHIC to default of "FALSE"
Default value of 64 assumed for HS_FDS_SQLLEN_INTERPRETATION
 setting HS_CALL_NAME_ISP to "gtw$:SQLTables;gtw$:SQLColumns;gtw$:SQLPrimaryKeys;gtw$:SQLForeignKeys;gtw$:SQLProcedures;gtw$:SQLStatistics;gtw$:SQLGetInfo;gtw$:OPTTables;gtw$:OPTColumns;gtw$:OPTPrimaryKeys;gtw$:OPTForeignKeys;gtw$:OPTProcedures;gtw$:OPTStatistics"
 setting HS_FDS_DELAYED_OPEN to default of "TRUE"
 setting HS_FDS_WORKAROUNDS to default of "0"
 setting HS_WORKAROUNDS to default of "0"
Exiting hgosdip, rc=0
 ORACLE_SID is "dg4odbc"
 Product-Info:
  Port Rls/Upd:0/0 PrdStat:0
  Agent:Oracle Database Gateway for ODBC
  Facility:hsa
  Class:ODBC, ClassVsn:18.0.0.0.0_0024, Instance:dg4odbc
Exiting hgogprd, rc=0
HOA 11/20 21:31:04.583891000: (hotker_ExecuteRpcs) ncrorpi: status  = 0
HOA 11/20 21:31:04.588171000: (hotker_ExecuteRpcs) ncrorpi: status  = 0
Entered hgoinit
HOCXU_COMP_CSET=1
HOCXU_DRV_CSET=873
HOCXU_DRV_NCHAR=873
HOCXU_DB_CSET=873
HS_LANGUAGE not specified
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
HOCXU_SEM_VER=122020
HOCXU_VC2_MAX=4000
HOCXU_RAW_MAX=2000
Entered hgolofn at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
HOSGIP for "HS_FDS_SHAREABLE_NAME" returned "/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.2.so.0.1"
Entered hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
 symbol_peflctx=0xd888b020
 hoaerr:0
Exiting hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
Entered hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
 symbol_peflctx=0xd88b1970
 hoaerr:0
Exiting hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
Entered hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
 symbol_peflctx=0xd88bcf20
 hoaerr:0
Exiting hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
Entered hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
 symbol_peflctx=0xd88ce080
 hoaerr:0
Exiting hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
Entered hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
 symbol_peflctx=0xd88bedf0
 hoaerr:0
Exiting hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
Entered hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
 symbol_peflctx=0xd888c200
 hoaerr:0
Exiting hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
Entered hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
 symbol_peflctx=0xd88e7e80
 hoaerr:0
Exiting hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
Entered hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
 symbol_peflctx=0xd885fb90
 hoaerr:0
Exiting hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
Entered hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
 symbol_peflctx=0xd88dc660
 hoaerr:0
Exiting hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
Entered hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
 symbol_peflctx=0xd888b400
 hoaerr:0
Exiting hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
Entered hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
 symbol_peflctx=0xd884e2f0
 hoaerr:0
Exiting hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
Entered hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
 symbol_peflctx=0xd88a45c0
 hoaerr:0
Exiting hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
Entered hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
 symbol_peflctx=0xd88ce7f0
 hoaerr:0
Exiting hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
Entered hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
 symbol_peflctx=0xd88cb230
 hoaerr:0
Exiting hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
Entered hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
 symbol_peflctx=0xd88dd000
 hoaerr:0
Exiting hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
Entered hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
 symbol_peflctx=0xd88b45e0
 hoaerr:0
Exiting hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
Entered hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
 symbol_peflctx=0xd885bdd0
 hoaerr:0
Exiting hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
Entered hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
 symbol_peflctx=0xd88558e0
 hoaerr:0
Exiting hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
Entered hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
 symbol_peflctx=0xd88ac9e0
 hoaerr:0
Exiting hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
Entered hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
 symbol_peflctx=0xd88ce6b0
 hoaerr:0
Exiting hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
Entered hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
 symbol_peflctx=0xd88bacf0
 hoaerr:0
Exiting hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
Entered hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
 symbol_peflctx=0xd88b3f60
 hoaerr:0
Exiting hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
Entered hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
 symbol_peflctx=0xd88a6980
 hoaerr:0
Exiting hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
Entered hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
 symbol_peflctx=0xd888f2f0
 hoaerr:0
Exiting hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
Entered hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
 symbol_peflctx=0xd88b5050
 hoaerr:0
Exiting hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
Entered hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
 symbol_peflctx=0xd888c7f0
 hoaerr:0
Exiting hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
Entered hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
 symbol_peflctx=0xd8860450
 hoaerr:0
Exiting hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
Entered hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
 symbol_peflctx=0xd88a7710
 hoaerr:0
Exiting hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
Entered hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
 symbol_peflctx=0xd88db300
 hoaerr:0
Exiting hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
Entered hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
 symbol_peflctx=0xd88b9ec0
 hoaerr:0
Exiting hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
Entered hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
 symbol_peflctx=0xd88b9690
 hoaerr:0
Exiting hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
Entered hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
 symbol_peflctx=0xd88c45d0
 hoaerr:0
Exiting hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
Entered hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
 symbol_peflctx=0xd88c45b0
 hoaerr:0
Exiting hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
Entered hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
 symbol_peflctx=0xd88cd980
 hoaerr:0
Exiting hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
Entered hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
 symbol_peflctx=0xd88d02d0
 hoaerr:0
Exiting hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
Entered hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
 symbol_peflctx=0xd88a8890
 hoaerr:0
Exiting hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
Entered hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
 symbol_peflctx=0xd8857390
 hoaerr:0
Exiting hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
Entered hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
 symbol_peflctx=0xd88a7470
 hoaerr:0
Exiting hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
Entered hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
 symbol_peflctx=0xd88a8540
 hoaerr:0
Exiting hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
Entered hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
 symbol_peflctx=0xd88a8270
 hoaerr:0
Exiting hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
Entered hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
 symbol_peflctx=0xd88d9f90
 hoaerr:0
Exiting hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
Entered hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
 symbol_peflctx=0xd88cf8e0
 hoaerr:0
Exiting hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
Entered hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
 symbol_peflctx=0xd88bc190
 hoaerr:0
Exiting hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
Entered hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
 symbol_peflctx=0xd88a6cb0
 hoaerr:0
Exiting hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
Entered hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
 symbol_peflctx=0xd88a6620
 hoaerr:0
Exiting hgolofns at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
Exiting hgolofn, rc=0 at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
HOSGIP for "HS_OPEN_CURSORS" returned "50"
HOSGIP for "HS_FDS_FETCH_ROWS" returned "100"
HOSGIP for "HS_LONG_PIECE_TRANSFER_SIZE" returned "65536"
HOSGIP for "HS_NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS" returned ".,"
HOSGIP for "HS_KEEP_REMOTE_COLUMN_SIZE" returned "OFF"
HOSGIP for "HS_FDS_DELAYED_OPEN" returned "TRUE"
HOSGIP for "HS_FDS_WORKAROUNDS" returned "0"
HOSGIP for "HS_FDS_MBCS_TO_GRAPHIC" returned "FALSE"
HOSGIP for "HS_FDS_GRAPHIC_TO_MBCS" returned "FALSE"
Invalid value of 64 given for HS_FDS_SQLLEN_INTERPRETATION
treat_SQLLEN_as_compiled = 1
Exiting hgoinit, rc=0 at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
Entered hgolgon at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
 reco:0, name:waproking, tflag:0
Entered hgosuec at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
Exiting hgosuec, rc=0 at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
HOSGIP for "HS_FDS_RECOVERY_ACCOUNT" returned "waproking"
HOSGIP for "HS_FDS_TRANSACTION_LOG" returned "HS_TRANSACTION_LOG"
HOSGIP for "HS_FDS_TIMESTAMP_MAPPING" returned "DATE"
HOSGIP for "HS_FDS_DATE_MAPPING" returned "DATE"
HOSGIP for "HS_FDS_TRUNC_ANSI_DATE" returned "OFF"
HOSGIP for "HS_FDS_MAP_NCHAR" returned "TRUE"
HOSGIP for "HS_FDS_RESULTSET_SUPPORT" returned "FALSE"
HOSGIP for "HS_FDS_RSET_RETURN_ROWCOUNT" returned "FALSE"
HOSGIP for "HS_FDS_PROC_IS_FUNC" returned "FALSE"
HOSGIP for "HS_FDS_REPORT_REAL_AS_DOUBLE" returned "FALSE"
 using waproking as default schema
HOSGIP for "HS_SQL_HANDLE_STMT_REUSE" returned "FALSE"
Entered hgocont at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
 HS_FDS_CONNECT_INFO = "MSSQL"
 RC=-1 from HOSGIP for "HS_FDS_CONNECT_STRING"
Entered hgogenconstr at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
 dsn:MSSQL, name:waproking
 optn:
Entered hgocip at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
 dsn:MSSQL
Exiting hgocip, rc=0 at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
Exiting hgogenconstr, rc=0 at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
Entered hgopoer at 2018/11/20-21:31:04
```

MSSQL Server Logs:

```
2018-11-20 21:27:40.75 Logon       Błąd: 18456; ważność: 14; stan: 58.
2018-11-20 21:27:40.75 Logon       Login failed for user ''. Przyczyna: Próba logowania z użyciem uwierzytelniania programu SQL Server nie powiodła się. Serwer jest skonfigurowany tylko do obsługi uwierzytelniania systemu Windows. [KLIENT: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX]
```

the mssql database is configured in mixed mode, and connections to it operate from the oracle 11g database

**my attention was drawn by an empty username in the MSSQL!**

```
2018-11-20 21:27:40.75 Logon       Login failed for user ''
```

Anyone can suggest something? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `HS_NLS_NCHAR=UCS2`. `UnixODBC` drivers can't support `UTF-8` character sets. May be you need other variables in your `initXX.ora`, but try this one now. Best regards.